# Would this information storing circuit work

Tags: logic-gates

So I tried to make a information circuit which when switch is pressed, and thus turning the led on, it maintains that true state even after switch is opened but I am not entirely sure if I built it correctly.Does the led need a resister?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f5cFbt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Sorry for the confusion guys. Edited the diagram and description. Dont worry about the value of the capacitor

Comment: I don't think that connecting the moon to your circuit would help. Seriously, there is a crescent in the schematic. There are also no logic gates in sight, just two npn bipolar junction transistors, of which one has a tumor attached.

Comment: This site has a built in circuit editor, you should use it.

Comment: What's the circuit supposed to do, and what's that crescent moon looking affair supposed to be?

Comment: May I suggest that you have a look at similar circuits that can easily be found by using google image search. Just look at them and see if you understand how they work. Also look at how they're drawn. Once you get an understanding of that, start drawing your own in the same way. Then come back and let us have a look at it.

Comment: Normal convention is to have the battery's minus at the bottom. When SW1 is open, the input of NOT1 and the left input of XOR1 are undefined, this is not allowed ! There is no current limiting resistor for the LED. One input of AND2 is connected via a capacitor, this is useless and will not work. You're interested in circuits, EXCELLENT ! Now have a look at how others make circuits and how these work. You have to understand that if you want to make your own !

Comment: Ok, Ill try to look for an image of this using google. This wasnt any serious work, it was just for fun and to challenge myself :P

Comment: Trust me, once you get an understanding, the real fun begins :-) Oh and the circuit we use to store information, but only one bit, is called a "flip flop".

Comment: Yes, the LED needs a resistor. If you don't have one, the current through the LED will heavily depend on the internal resistance of your XOR gate and the voltage accurancy and current capability of your Voltage supply. In other words, the LED will burn most likely.

Comment: A pull down resistor is needed after the switch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you could (as mentioned in comments) use a flip flop, this particular implementation is ripe for a "FET Trick" that would do what you want for quite some time...the capacitor is optional (& needs to be a low-leakage type if used), as the gate capacitance alone will work for quite some time - and I added a reset switch.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ftRa7c.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

It's also easily do-able as a nice olde fashioned relay logic circuit (light-bulb can be LED+ resistor, of course)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuyQVi.png)</sup>